# How to extract set of substrings from a paragraph of string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Say I have a string:

```
output='[{  "id":"b678792277461" ,"Responses":{"SUCCESS":{"sh xyz":"sh xyz\\n  Name                             Age            Height   Weight\\n  Ana                    \\u003c15 \\u003e             163        47\\n                                                                     43\\n  DEB                       \\u003c23 \\u003e             155        \\n  Grey                            \\u003c53 \\u003e             143       54\\n                                                                     63\\n  Sch#"},"FAILURE":{},"BLACKLISTED":{}}}]'
```

This is just an example but I have much longer output which is response from an api call.
I want to extract all names (`ana, dab, grey`) and put in a separate list.
how can I do it?

```
json_data = json.loads(output)

json_data = [{'id': 'b678792277461', 'Responses': {'SUCCESS': {'sh xyz': 'sh xyz\n  Name                             Age            Height   Weight\n  Ana                    <15 >             163        47\n                                                                     43\n  DEB                       <23 >             155        \n  Grey                            <53 >             143       54\n                                                                     63\n  Sch#'}, 'FAILURE': {}, 'BLACKLISTED': {}}}]
```

1) I have tried `re.findall('\\n(.+)\\u',output)`

but this didn't work because it says "incomplete sequence u"

2)

```
start = output.find('\\n')
end = output.find('\\u', start)
x=output[start:end]
```

But I couldn't figure out how to run this piece of code in loop to extract names

Thanks

Comment: Is the whole output a string?

Comment: @DYZ yes whole output is string

Comment: Are there no more quotes in the output? Not around the inner `{...}`?

Comment: @DYZ nope there are no more quotes its just single quotes at beginning and end of string

Comment: @DYZ sorry I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\u` object is not a letter and it cannot be matched. It is a part of a Unicode sequence. The following regex works, but it is kind of quirky. It looks for the beginning of each line, except for the first one, until the first space.

```
output = json_data[0]['Responses']['SUCCESS']['sh xyz']

pattern = "\n\s*([a-z]+)\s+"
result = re.findall(pattern, output, re.M | re.I)
#['Name', 'Ana', 'DEB', 'Grey']
```

Explanation of the pattern:

- start at a new line (\n)
- skip all spaces, if any (\s*)
- collect one or more letters ([a-z]+)
- skip at least one space (\s+)

Unfortunately, `"Name"` is also recognized as a name. If you know that it is always present in the first line, slice the list of the results:

```
result[1:]
#['Ana', 'DEB', 'Grey']
```

Comment: Im getting an empty string as output

Comment: I copied the string from your example. If you are getting a different output, then either your `output` is not a string or you do not present it properly in the question.

Comment: if I give print(type(output)) it is returning class<'str'>

Comment: Then your true `output` must be different from the `output` in the question. Please check carefully.

Comment: I can convert the output to json. Will that help?

Comment: It will surely help a lot, as I suggested in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I have added my json data in question

Comment: if you don't mind can you please explain what re.M and re.I mean?

Comment: re.I means ignore character case. re.M means go multiline.

Comment: can u explain this as well "\n\s*([a-z]+)\s+" ? Im new to python so sorry for bothering you.

Comment: This is not exactly related to this question but a similar doubt. How to extract  name if it appeared after "Student:"? For Example after every new line it showed Student:Ana...... Student:Deb...... Student:Grey

Comment: You may want to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I use regexr.com and play around with the regular expression until I get it right and then covert that into Python.

https://regexr.com/

I'm assuming the \n is the newline character here and I'll bet your \u error is caused by a line break. To use the multiline match in Python, you need to use that flag when you compile.

\n(.*)\n - this will be greedy and grab as many matches as possible (In the example it would grab the entire \nAna through 54\n

[{ "id":"678792277461" ,"Responses": {Name Age Height Weight\n Ana \u00315 \u003163 47\n 43\n Deb \u00323 \u003155 60 \n Grey \u00353 \u003144 54\n }]

```
import re
a = re.compile("\\n(.*)\\n", re.MULTILINE)
for responses in a.match(source):
    match = responses.split("\n") 
    # match[0] should be " Ana \u00315 \u003163 47"
    # match[1] should be " Deb \u00323 \u003155 60" etc.
```